# stripe payments CardInputWidget change the font color for input

Tags: .net

stripe payments CardInputWidget Is there an API for developers to change the color of input fonts？
How does this component, CardInputWidget, change the font color for input

Comment: have you checked the docs https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/com/stripe/android/view/CardInputWidget.html

Answer (score 0):

Set the theme style for CardInputWidget, as shown below.

Comment: <style name="Stripe.CardInputWidget.EditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">

Comment: After demo test input font color is the theme style inside the custom color effect!

Note that this style should be named the same as stripe's official source name.

The solution is for reference only